# Sails / Socket.io websocket blocked - how to fall back?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I have a sails.js / socket.io chat application with websocket and polling transports enabled. In my organisation, we have a proxy/firewall which blocks connection to ws:// protocol.

When I run the application in this environment, I can see the sails application trying to reconnect to websocket with output like this:

> WebSocket connection to
>   '*ws://.../socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket*' failed: 
>   **WebSocket is closed before the connection is established**.
>   sails.io.js:143
>           Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails...
>   *-|>*-  (**attempt #11**)

How do I make the application fallback to polling transport after 3rd attempt?

UPDATE:
I've just found this on the socket.io blog:

> Socket.IO never assumes that WebSocket will just work, because in
>   practice there’s a good chance that it won’t. Instead, it establishes
>   a connection with XHR or JSONP right away, and then attempts to
>   upgrade the connection to WebSocket.

Also, the described conditions only happen once in a time, most of the times it works ok with polling. Looks like the sails app sometime skips the XHR connection and tries websockets right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to have sessions enabled to make polling work correctly, so it may by the cause of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when i make deploy on Heroku, apparently he don't work well with polling.

I solved this by forcing transports for websocket.

In config/sockets:

```
transports: ["websocket"]
```

Add this line immediately after the sails.io.js. Because this file is in the pipeline i created a new file to put the script:

```
io.sails.transports=['websocket'];
```

More details in this link:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment/scaling

Comment: Hi. As is apparent from my question, I can't use websockets, so forcing it would not be the solution.

Comment: The point is avoid the transport with problem, in your case, force transport for polling should help.

Comment: Thanks for the point, but still, I don't want to force the transport, I just want it to fall back in case it doesn't work for some user.